# How do I avoid keeping views in memory? Do I need to set all objects to nil?

Tags: ios, memory, uikit

I'm new to programming and have been developing an iOS app over the last couple months. To me the app looks like its functionally really close to done but I hit an issue today that I think might be a bigger underlying problem.

When I dismissViewController in a navigation controller and go back to the view later it seems to still have the same values. I thought when I do a dismiss that view is destroyed and a new one created later. I've been trying to read about it and I think maybe its a memory cycle thing, the view is kept in memory because there are objects in the view that still have pointers? Is there some general rules on how to handle this? Should I be setting object to nil any time I leave a view controller?How to I make sure I'm not keeping unnecessary things in memory?

Comment: You could set all the values back to their defaults in the `viewDidLoad` method

Comment: If you're using ARC, then any strong reference (and most references are strong by default if you don't specify) will keep the object alive, even if you have dismissed the view.

Comment: @i_am_jrof: do I have an option? I thought you don't "use" ARC, thats just the way it works?

Comment: ARC is used by default now.
Most probably you have strong references to your ViewController, either get rid those and do [[ViewController allo] init] every time you push/present it OR if you want to keep your references then update your ViewController to reload the data in viewWillAppear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
If you create your view controller in the following manner, creating it and then pushing it(commented out line) or presenting it, then it is guaranteed that the ViewController will always have an initial state as defined by your initializtion code.

- (IBAction)showViewController: (UIButton *)sender {
    MyViewController *vc = [[MyViewController alloc] init];

    [self presentViewController: vc animated: YES completion: nil];
    //[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES]
}
```

Answer (score -1):

check the viewController you dismiss,if the properties has strong reference(strong,retain) point to parentViewController.